# Google Chart One query per row

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Sorry for this kind of question its my first time to use google chart so i dont know if this is possbile.

Here's my question:

is it possible to create a google chart which the 2nd column are both from different query ?
Here's the example:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['JAN', $query1],
                ['FEB', $query2],
```

Comment: yes it is possible. something giving you trouble?

Comment: @Whitehat Actually im done with this but in a different way, anyway sir if it is possible can you tell me how ? im not familiar with google chart.